# JDeveloper Error Pane Not Showing

Tags: ide, jdeveloper

I am using the JDeveloper IDE to build a Java application and, at some point, my error pane has stopped appearing to display compile errors.

When I alter the code to intentionally produce errors during compilation (such as deleting a required parenthesis or brace, etc), I will be informed that there were errors during compilation within the "Messages - Log" window.  However, I cannot find the window which describes the errors occuring and their location in the code.

Basically, I just want to access the window that lists the errors found, what class they are located in and what line or method they are in.  How do I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try from menu `Window > Reset Windows to Factory Settings`.

Comment: Thank you.  I missed that option before.  I appreciate the help.